# apache-log4j-extras also declares `Appender` interface

Tags: java, apache, logging, log4j

My classpath, as generated by Gradle, includes both `apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar`, and `log4j-1.2.17.jar`. I believe these were both downloaded from Maven Central. In any case, in files I have in front of me, all the class and interface definitions from the `log4j` jar in the `org.apache.log4j` package are *duplicated* in the "extras" jar. When log4j is initialized, there's a class-loading conflict:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender cannot be cast to org.apache.log4j.Appender
```

What's the easiest thing to do here? Simply build and publish the JAR of "extras" to my company's Ivy server? I don't know why you'd redeclare the `Appender` interface.

Comment: No worries. I simply moved all my logging to Logback!

Comment: Just been bitten by this problem. From the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/) it is not clear whether `apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar` should be considered an add-on or a replacement for `log4j-1.2.17.jar`.

Comment: The Maven Central POM for `apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar` does reference `log4j-1.2.17.jar` as a dependency, but the former also contains a significant subset of the classes contained in the latter.